# Save documents as folders, like Pages, Numbers, etc

Tags: cocoa, macos

What's the right way to go about saving data like Pages, Numbers and other OSX applications do? That is, it looks like a file to the user, but is in fact a directory (a bundle?) containing a variety of stuff. I have some fairly complex data that I'd like to store in the same way; in particular, some sensor data that needs to be associated with video files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Apple [official docs on the topic](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Concepts/DocumentBundles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002128-BAJCGCFF) are probably a good starting point.

From the Pages Info.plist file:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>pages</string>
        </array>
        [...]
        <key>LSTypeIsPackage</key>
        <true/>
        [...]
    </dict>
</array>
```

seem to be what does the trick.

Comment: Ahh, that's it! A remarkably difficult topic to search upon without knowing what it's called!

Answer (score 1):

It also looks like `NSFileWrapper` may be part of the answer:
[Document-Based Applications Overview FAQ](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/Tasks/FAQ.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000954-1081069-BAJHBHGJ).